# Access - program a Union query to calc %'s within itself?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm very new to access, and teaching myself as I go. I'm trying to manipulate SQL code into doing what I want without really understanding it completely, so I'm running into a lot of issues. Before you reply with "I don't understand why you're doing it this way, you should be doing it this way", please help me find out if there IS a way to do this in the manner I am approaching it, since this took a long time for my brain to figure out, but if there truly is a simpler, better way, please explain it in detail to me, otherwise it's just gonna confuse me a lot more.

Before I post all my nonsense below, my main question is - **

is there a way to program a Union query via SQL to calculate percentages within itself?

** Like, the first query gives me a total, and the next query gives me new totals based on criterion, but needs an additional field to tell me what the % is compared to the first query.

Okay, on to my nonsense that hopefully explains what I'm trying to do effectively -

I need the report to look like this (edit: sorry, it doesn't look like it did when I wrote the post):

> Total Cases         Disputed Dollar Total             Percentage
>
> All Holds                                   11
>   $38,812.86
>
> All Approved                           7
>   $27,131.32                                     % (of All Holds)
>
> Appr w/o Resub                     5
>   $14,009.27                                   % (of All Appr)
>
> Appr w/ Resub                       2
>   $13,122.05                                    % (of All Appr)
>
> All Declined                            4
>   $11,681.54                                     % (of All Holds)
>
> Decl w/o Resub                      3
>   $7,816.14                                       % (of All Decl)
>
> Decl w/ Resub                        1
>   $3,865.40                                      % (of All Decl)

I'm using a Union query to stick all the queries I need into one report.

Here is the complete SQL code (sorry it's so long). Ignore the "select null" pieces, they are my bandaid to get the report to separate where I need it to. It just links to an empty table.

```
> SELECT "All Holds" As Type, Count([Holds Table].[Date email received])
> AS [CountOfDate email received], Sum([Holds Table].[Disputed Dollar
> Amount]) AS [SumOfDisputed Dollar Amount] FROM [Holds Table] WHERE
> ((([Holds Table].[Date email received]) Between [Enter start date:]
> And [Enter end date:]))
> 
> UNION ALL 
> 
> SELECT null as Type, null as [CountOfDate email received], null as
> [SumOfDisputed Dollar Amount] from [extra] 
> 
> UNION ALL
> 
> SELECT "All Approved" As Type, Count([Holds Table].[Date email
> received]) AS [CountOfDate email received], Sum([Holds
> Table].[Disputed Dollar Amount]) AS [SumOfDisputed Dollar Amount] FROM
> [Holds Table] WHERE ((([Holds Table].[Date email received]) Between
> [Enter start date:] And [Enter end date:])) GROUP BY [Holds
> Table].[SHU Decision] HAVING ((([Holds Table].[SHU Decision])="1"))
> 
> UNION ALL
> 
> SELECT"Approved without Resubmission" As type,  Count([Holds
> Table].[Date email received]) AS [CountOfDate email received],
> Sum([Holds Table].[Disputed Dollar Amount]) AS [SumOfDisputed Dollar
> Amount] FROM [Holds Table] WHERE ((([Holds Table].[Date email
> received]) Between [Enter start date:] And [Enter end date:])) GROUP
> BY [Holds Table].[SHU Decision], [Holds Table].[Resubmitted?] HAVING
> ((([Holds Table].[SHU Decision])="1") AND (([Holds
> Table].[Resubmitted?])=False))
> 
> UNION ALL 
> 
> SELECT"Approved with Resubmission" As type,  Count([Holds Table].[Date
> email received]) AS [CountOfDate email received], Sum([Holds
> Table].[Disputed Dollar Amount]) AS [SumOfDisputed Dollar Amount] FROM
> [Holds Table] WHERE ((([Holds Table].[Date email received]) Between
> [Enter start date:] And [Enter end date:])) GROUP BY [Holds
> Table].[SHU Decision], [Holds Table].[Resubmitted?] HAVING ((([Holds
> Table].[SHU Decision])="1") AND (([Holds Table].[Resubmitted?])=True))
> 
> UNION ALL 
> 
> Select null as Type, null as [CountOfDate email received], null as
> [SumOfDisputed Dollar Amount] from [extra] 
> 
> UNION ALL 
> 
> SELECT "All Declined" As Type, Count([Holds Table].[Date email
> received]) AS [CountOfDate email received], Sum([Holds
> Table].[Disputed Dollar Amount]) AS [SumOfDisputed Dollar Amount] FROM
> [Holds Table] WHERE ((([Holds Table].[Date email received]) Between
> [Enter start date:] And [Enter end date:])) GROUP BY [Holds
> Table].[SHU Decision] HAVING ((([Holds Table].[SHU Decision])="2"))
> 
> UNION ALL 
> 
> SELECT "Declined without Resubmission" As type, Count([Holds
> Table].[Date email received]) AS [CountOfDate email received],
> Sum([Holds Table].[Disputed Dollar Amount]) AS [SumOfDisputed Dollar
> Amount] FROM [Holds Table] WHERE ((([Holds Table].[Date email
> received]) Between [Enter start date:] And [Enter end date:])) GROUP
> BY [Holds Table].[SHU Decision], [Holds Table].[Resubmitted?] HAVING
> ((([Holds Table].[SHU Decision])="2") AND (([Holds
> Table].[Resubmitted?])=False))
> 
> UNION ALL 
> 
> SELECT "Declined with Resubmit" As type, Count([Holds Table].[Date
> email received]) AS [CountOfDate email received], Sum([Holds
> Table].[Disputed Dollar Amount]) AS [SumOfDisputed Dollar Amount] FROM
> [Holds Table] WHERE ((([Holds Table].[Date email received]) Between
> [Enter start date:] And [Enter end date:])) GROUP BY [Holds
> Table].[SHU Decision], [Holds Table].[Resubmitted?] HAVING ((([Holds
> Table].[SHU Decision])="2") AND (([Holds
> Table].[Resubmitted?])=True));
```

*phew* So, is this even possible or am I just screwed? I know exactly how to calculate all of this in Excel, within seconds, so I'm getting really frustrated that I can't do things that seem logical to me in Access without hours of scouring the internet for code I don't understand. That aside, I would appreciate any help you can give me, or even a "you ARE screwed, maybe try it this way". Much obliged!

Comment: I suggest you: remove all meaningless comments like "phew So, is this even possible or am I just screwed?", because makes dificult understand you.

Comment: And where is the table definition? example data?

Comment: Are you just talking about the formatting of your output? Why doesn't your code generate what you expect?

Comment: My code doesn't generate what I expect because what I need isn't written into it yet. I am trying to figure out HOW to write it in.

Answer (score 0):

> ..is there a way to program a Union query via SQL to calculate
>   percentages within itself?

Short answer is: No

You should move the individual queries to subqueries, then have a main query that pulls the data you need from these.

Comment: Just bing/google on SQL tutorials. Plenty of these out there.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!